# Storing view count into database

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, erd

I want to store a video view counts in a Database(MySQL)

i want to store every visitor IP address (and some other information)

So i created a Table with (VidoId,Ip,Date,UserAgent)

Now my problem is everytime i want to show view count i have to execute this query :

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Views WHERE VideoId = xxx
```

i know i can store this into a column on my videos table and update it on every insert. but this will create a fragmentation and break data consistently also it's not possible to model it with EER.
also i know i can cache it.

i just want to know is there any way to do this both efficiently and modelable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical way to handle this is to create a separate table that aggregates data for an entity.  In your case, it would be a video_aggregate table with the following columns:

VideoId (primary key), NumberOfViews

Here are some big advantages that I think outweigh the effort of adding another table:

1. Very quick reads, and only one simple join if you need to combine it with video data
2. No locking/blocking on your Video table every time someone views a video.  In fact, the update to both the views and the video_aggregate table could (and probably should) be asynchronous.  It can tolerate a little latency.
3. The number of views is not an attribute of a video--does not describe that entity at all.  It describes a user activity.  This may seem pedantic, but it's essential to expert modeling and will play out well over time when you take this kind of care in a relational database model.

p.s. Call your table something more specific than "Views," such as "VideoViews."

p.p.s. I might add that this solution is essentially adding a simple "fact table" from multidimensional modeling.  When you get around to a data warehouse, it will go there.

Answer (score 0):

To do this efficiently, create an index on `Views(VideoId)`:

```
create index idx_views_videoid on Views(VideoId);
```

The query should then be fast enough for most applications.